# Can a creature use an immediate reaction after another creature's opportunity action on a third creature's turn?

Tags: dnd-4e, battlemind, mark, opportunity-actions, immediate-reaction

My battlemind and a cleric were engaged in a melee battle with a Deathdog the other day.  The cleric was knocked down on a previous turn, so that when her turn began she attempted to stand up.  The deathdog, who was **marked** by the battlemind, responded with it's opportunity action:

> **Go for the Legs** (opportunity , when an
>   adjacent enemy stands up; at-will) ***
>   Necrotic**
>
> The deathdog makes a pouncing bite
>   attack against the triggering
>   creature; 1d10 + 4

Knocking the cleric down and dealing damage.

> Mind Spike
>   **At-Will + Force, Psionic, Psychic**
>   **Immediate Reaction  Melee 1**
>   **Trigger:** An  adjacent enemy marked by you deals
>   damage to  your ally with an attack
>   that doesn't include you  as a target
>   **Target:** The  triggering enemy
>   **Effect:** The  target takes force and psychic
>   damage equal to  the damage that its
>   attack dealt to your ally.

Can my Battlemind then use **Mind Spike** on the Deathdog?

Comment: Did someone  make the argument that you couldn't use the Mind Spike?

Comment: No, the group played it as fair, but we weren't exactly sure if that was the correct call.  I think I was confused by how a creature can't interrupt an interrupt on their own turn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**,

An Immediate action can be used once between your turns.  As long as it isn't your turn, your Immediate Action can be used whenever its trigger condition is met.

Comment: Actually, you can only take one immediate action per round.

Comment: @JStrange "Once between your turns" is effectively once per round for PCs, as there are a number of rules in place to ensure that they do not have more than one turn in a round.  Additionally "once between your turns" is perhaps a more concise and accurate specification than "once per round", per this clause in the "Immediate Action" rule:  *If you take an immediate action, you can’t take another one until the start of your next turn, but you can’t take an immediate action on your own turn.*

Comment: I wasn't quibbling about once per round vs. once between turns, just pointing out that you can't use immediate actions whenever their trigger conditions are met as long as it isn't your turn. You get one.

Comment: @jst - I would direct you to the first sentence of my answer.